# Nonlinear System of Integral Equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, integral-equations

I have encountered a system of nonlinear integral equations in my work. They take the form
$$\int_{0}^{1} g(y)e^{f(x)g(y)}(x+f(x)g(y)-f(x))dy=0$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)g(y)^2 e^{f(x)g(y)}(y+f(x)g(y)-f(x))dx=0$$

The goal is to find (or prove the existence of) real functions $f$ and $g$ satisfying the above equations.
I have gathered that this would be called a "nonlinear system of homogeneous Fredholm equations of the first kind."

I have somewhat limited experience with integral equations. Some of my questions (I would appreciate insights into any of them!)

1. Is it reasonable to expect that there is a method to find an explicit form for $f$ and $g$?
2. Can somebody point me to a reference that describes dealing with systems of integral equations? The sources that I have looked at on integral equations so far tend to deal with primarily a single integral equation with a single unknown function.
3. Are there techniques that you know of that may be worth applying to such a system?
4. My only (naive) idea for approaching it is to Taylor expand everything in sight and see if it is possible to extract conditions on the coefficients for $f$ and $g$. Does it seem possible that this will give useful information?
5. Is there any theorem like the Picard-Linelof theorem (existence and uniqueness) for integral equations?

If it's worth anything, I know a few conditions that the functions $f$ and $g$ should satisfy. I know for example that $g$ should be non-increasing and $f$ should be non-decreasing; $g(0)=1$ and $f(0)=0$.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Is $g(0)=1$ a given condition or was it deduced from the equations ? Are there conditions on continuity ? A non continuous solution is $g(x)=0,x\neq 0$ and f can be anything.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The hope is to find continuous solutions, yes. It is possible to deduce g(0)=1 directly from the equations, though the derivation is a bit long.